# polymer cli Promise rejection: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: build, polymer, command-line-interface

How to debug polymer-cli polymer build.
during a build process i got an error
Promise rejection: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
I assume it is because some dependencies between packages but i don't know how to debug the build process to find out which package causes it.
The proflem is with
'/bower_components/paper-styles/element-styles/paper-material.html'
in my version I have 
'/bower_components/paper-styles/element-styles/paper-material-styles.html'

Answer (score 0):

Search your project as well as your bower_components directory for any references to `paper-material.html` and replace them with `paper-material-styles.html` (if there are references to that in your bower_components directory, hopefully you just have to update whatever component that is to its latest version). The file was renamed to address a bug, see https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/issues/130